# A word that means fill it to the required quantity

Tags: word-request

> The jug of milk half full, so he took a glass of water and *.

I am not sure if there's a word for it, but I guess if there lacks a word for it there's a phrase that sounds better than "fill it to the required quantity". What word or phrase would you use?

Comment: By the way, it should be "the jug of milk **was** half full". Several answer correct this without mentioning it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you specifically mean the vessel has some liquid in, but not enough, and you are adding more liquid - the same sort, or a different one - to fill it to a required level, that's the phrasal verb ***to top up***<sup>1</sup>.

> The jug of milk was half full, so he took a glass of water and **topped it up**.

Phrased a bit more naturally:

> The jug of milk was half full, so he **topped it up** with water.

(Topping it up with water sound a bit weird, but okay)

You get this in cocktail recipes:

> Cut a lime into quarters and place two quarters into the glass. Add the gomme syrup (or sugar) and rum and muddle together, making sure you squeeze the juice out of the limes. Fill with crushed ice and **top up with soda** (or apple juice for an apple mojito). Add the sprigs of mint and tease to the bottom of the glass with a spoon, at the same time as gently lifting the lime, sugar and rum upwards.

(From [The Guardian's beginner's guide to making cocktails](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2008/dec/09/how-to-make-cocktails))

You can also use that for materials other than liquids - you might talk about topping up your liquor cabinet, or your supply of pasta. It can even be for immaterial things, like topping up your mobile (cellular) phone's credit, or topping up your bank account by selling unwanted possessions. In these other contexts, it doesn't usually carry the connotation of filling to a specified level, it just means that you think there's not enough and you should get some more.

---

<sup>1</sup>: At least, in British English; American English apparently uses "top off", which we use... differently, in British English.

Comment: In AmE we'd say _top it off_ rather than _up_.

Comment: @Kevin: Interesting. We use *top off* as well, but it has a different meaning. It would mean to add something different on top, as a way of "finishing" it, like having a dessert that's, say, fruit fool - which is a fine dessert on its own - "topped off" with cream, meaning some cream added to the top. If we talk about a bad situation, and say a final bit "to top it off", that's like saying "the icing on the cake".

Comment: @SamBC In my experience (in Canada), both uses of "top it off" would probably work, in context.  For example, if you had a drink and someone else was pouring drinks, asking someone to "top it off" would be understood as filling their cup the remainder of the way.  The use of "and to top it all off" is still the same as you're describing it though.  "Top it up" would almost definitely be understood; but "top it off" sounds more idiomatic for me.

Comment: Interesting indeed. We do use _and to top it (all) off_ as well, but I feel like it doesn't sound right without the _and_ except maybe in baking directions (_top it off with_…), but even then I feel like  _top(ped) with_, without the _off_, is more common.

Answer (score 8):

He took a glass of water and **filled it up.**

Verb: to fill something up, not necessarily to the brim.

Answer (score 5):

> [**top (something / someone) up**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/top)
>    *Fill up a glass or other partly full container*

...where "something" would be a container *(your glass, my car fuel tank)*, and "someone" would be *a person whose container needs to be refilled* (hence *Can I top you up?* = *Can I refill your beer glass / coffee cup?*).

Answer (score 0):

**replenish**

A more formal option to the previous answers.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/replenish

> replenish
>
> verb
>
> to fill something up again

Examples include:

> The jug of milk half full, so he took a glass of water and replenished it with water/milk.
>
> The jug of milk half full, so he took a glass of water and replenished it.